# The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)

Tags: windows-7, regedit

System = Windows 7 64-bit

Various programs, notably Regedit, won't start.  Instead I get:

The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).

Strangly, at least to my thinking, I can launch them via Task Manager.

I am also grappling with AVG errors or over-activity, e.g. reports of Broken digital Signature.

I am also having problems with Excel Update KB978474

I mention these just incase anyone thinks there is a connection, rather than expecting people to solve 3 problems at once.

Comment: Could be affected with Virus/Malware. Use some anti-virus programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sound like you have a corrupt or virus-infected files,

try`SFC /scannow` to recover the system files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I eventually got SFC / scannow to work in safe mode.  It reports corrupted files that it could not repair.

Restore points don't go back very far.  Is it easy / possible to repair the corrupted files, or should I go for a complete system repair / rebuild?

Comment: whats the exact message SFC is reporting ? SFC is just replacing the modified system files by the originals ones from the CD.(the only way I know to recover corrupted files) you may need to check your hard drive for errors, make sure he's intact.

Comment: [Thank you for your continued interest in my problem] Error Example from SFC: - Hashes for file member \??\C:\Windows\System32\NlsData0039.dll do not match actual file Could not reproject corrupted file

Comment: pleased to help